# Difference between sum of two record sets grouped by the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

I need to write a SQL query to calculate the difference in revenues between Europe and Asia. I am constrained by the app dev and cannot calculate this in 2 steps (compute the totals in each continent separately then calculate the difference)

Here is the db:

```
Sales(s_key, s_key, s_product, s_date, s_amount, s_quantity) 

Customer(c_key, c_name, c_city, c_country, c_continent)
```

Can you help me extend this query which calculates the revenue in Europe to get difference with revenue in Asia?
Thank you!

```
Select Sum(s_amount)
From Sales
Where c_continent = 'Europe'
Group By c_continent
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select  sum(case s_continent
            when 'Europe' then s_amount 
            when 'Asia' then -s_amount 
            end) as EuropeMinusAsia
from    Sales
```

Comment: Thank you Andomar. This is not the standard SQL, right?
Do I need to install another plugin to support this query?

Comment: Looks fairly standard to me - Maybe `-1 * s_amount` is more usual

Comment: I mean the Case clause within the sum function. Is it a standard SQL code?

Comment: `sum(case ...` is part of basic SQL, all databases I know support it out of the box